# MTR installation and configuration file

Tags: 14.04, configuration, installed-programs, traceroute

I apologise in advance as this is probably lack of knowledge on my part. But for the life of me and even consulting the all knowing google and man pages / help pages. I can find out where MTR is installed to and if there is a configuration file where I can statically set the **O**rder of the columns.

This seems like something so simple. But its stumped me.

Can someone lend a hand?

Thanks
Andy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software) |
https://github.com/traviscross/mtr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short; I was overthinking it. I thought I would need to change the columns in a config file when actually I can just create an alias to handle it for all users.

Created a file in /etc/profile.d called 00-aliases.sh containing:

```
alias mtr='mtr -o LSR NABWV'
```

So that when I type MTR it uses the alias with the columns. Seems a viable solution unless someone can offer better.

(Obviously dont forget to set the file as e**x**ecutable).